# Do I need an Artificial Intelligence API?

Tags: machine-learning, java

I'm wondering if programmers tend to use AI APIs. And if so, what are they like? And where can I find a nice one for Java?

Comment: Define AI first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to use an *artificial intelligence (AI)* API, if there is a need to add *AI functionality* to a software application - this is pretty obvious. Traditionally, my advice on *machine learning (ML)* software includes the following two excellent **curated lists** of resources: [this one](https://github.com/onurakpolat/awesome-bigdata) and [this one](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning).

However, keep in mind that ML is just a **subset** of AI domain, so if your tasks involve AI areas *beyond* ML, you need more *AI-focused* tools or platforms. For example, you can take a look at [ai-one](http://www.ai-one.com)'s AI platforms and APIs as well as interesting *general AI* open source project [OpenCog](http://opencog.org).

In addition to the above-mentioned AI-focused platforms, IBM's [Watson](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson) AI system deserves a separate mention, as quite cool and promising. It offers its own *ecosystem* for developers, called [IBM Watson Developer Cloud](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud), based on IBM's [BlueMix](https://ace.ng.bluemix.net) cloud computing *platform-as-a-service (PaaS)*. However, at the present time, I find this offering to be quite expensive as well as limiting, especially for individual developers, small startups and other small businesses, due to its tight integration with and reliance only on a single PaaS (Blue Mix). It will be interesting to watch this space as competition in AI domain and marketplace IMHO will surely intensify in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Java much but have you looked into machine learning with the Weka Java API?  You might also try Encog, mentioned [here](http://www.jeffheaton.com/ai/), and if you search for *Practical Artificial Intelligence Programming With Java* by Mark Watson, you might still be able to find a PDF version that's licensed for free non-commercial use.